# Ubuntu 18.04 won't boot up after successful installation (dual-boot, external hard drive)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 18.04, grub2, system-installation

Please help me! I'm new to Ubuntu and trying to get it working for days now. I'm installing Ubuntu 18.04 to dual-boot with my exisiting system, Windows 10. I've never done anything like this before.

**[ Installation details ] (skip below to see the actual problem)**

After several problems and error messages I managed to install Ubuntu the following way:

I have downloaded Ubuntu 18.04 from the official site

I created a bootable USB stick using Rufus

Tried boot from the USB stick and install (Entering BIOS with F2, then choose the UEFI boot option) here got a lot of errors:

- I could not create the required partition (at the installer choose "Something else" setting up the partitions manually), because my HDD-s limit is 4 primary partitions (and ereasing the HDD is not an option for me), so I used an external HDD and tried to create the partitions there
- Now I had no problem with the limit, but got the following error message:

> The partition /dev/sdf3 assigned to / starts at an offset of 1024
> bytes from the minimum alignment for this disk, which may lead to very
> poor performance.

- This was resolved by remaking the whole partitioning process using GParted, now the installer worked just fine until the very end, where I got the error message:

> 'grub-efi-amd64-signed' package failed to install...

- After many more hours of bugfixing, I resolved this by the following attempt:

  Still using external HDD, the two main partitions for "/" and "/home" are preapared using GParted, a 200 MB partition is also created by GParted as flat32 with "boot" flag and it's changed in the Ubuntu installer to "EFI-Partition". I turned off Fast Boot and Secure Boot in the BIOS and finally the installer finished succesfully.

**[ Boot up problem ]**

While booting up now, if I let it go, it starts windows as default. I can't acces the Grub menu. If I try pressing `Shift` or `Esc` it at startup, it does nothing. (The external HDD with the Ubuntu installation is of course plugged in at all times)

If I manually go to the boot menu using F8, I see 3 options:

- one is my default HDD with the Windows. If I choose that it starts the Windows
- another option is "ubuntu" just like this, full lower case. If I choose this it also starts Windows after a bit of thinking
- and the last one is my external HDD. If I choose this, it gets to a black screen with a white underscore flashing a basically stuck here forever, I let it for a half hour and nothing. I've read that you can try different combinations here, `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `F1`,`F2`,...,`F12` they didn't do anything either. I've also read that you can change Grub config files somehow, but I can't access Ubuntu at all.

I've also tried changing boot priorities in BIOS, but it didn't result any change.

Boot report: [paste.ubuntu.com/p/yqChHrXMvJ](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/yqChHrXMvJ)

Any advice would be appreciated. I can provide more information if I missed something important.

Comment: Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair  If you have UEFI/gpt, then you do not have a 4 partition limit. Any issues with shrinking Windows were probably from not using Windows tools to shrink the NTFS partition and leaving Windows fast start up/hibernation on.

Comment: Here is the boot report: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/yqChHrXMvJ/

Comment: In case you would ask: Yes, I'm aware that it says, 2 Ubuntus are installed, it's because before the external HDD, I tried to install Ubuntu to the internal HDD in an incorrect way and I did not format it yet. However that installation was never complete. Can that cause the problem? In which case I'll try to format that

Comment: You have mixed up BIOS and UEFI. So you must have newer UEFI hardware, but have Windows installed in old BIOS/MBR on sda. Microsoft has required vendors to install in UEFI boot mode since 2012, but users choose install mode by how they boot install media for both Windows & Ubuntu. If you boot live installer in BIOS mode, & add Boot-Repair, you should be able to install BIOS version of grub to sda. Note in BIOS mode you really need both a Windows repair/recovery flash drive & Ubuntu live installer. Grub only boots working Windows, and Windows will turn fast start up back on & then you repair.